# link cut, find length and cut the new text with the first text's length

Tags: shell-script

I'm stuck up with the below situation.

there are two files - sample.war & sample1.48.war
now, I've to cut only the first field of the first file. i.e., 'sample'.
Next, I've to count the total number of text in 'sample' and cut only those many characters in file 2 (sample1.48.war)
if these two characters matches , then do some operation & if not, some other operation.

Comment: Sounds like a nice riddle :-). What have you tried sofar, how do the input files look like, what should the desired output look like? Please enrich your question with some better details.

Comment: @Lambert, here is what I've tried so far. 1. I've extracted the first part of the sample.war using cut command. 2. I've found the length of the string using wc -c. So, the first part is done... Next thing is I've to cut the sample1.48.war with the length I've got from (2). I'm stuck there.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo=sample.war
bar=sample1.48.war

echo $bar | cut -c $(echo $foo | wc -c)-
```

give

```
.war
```

- `cut -c 1-7` will keep 1st to 7th char
- `cut -c 8-`  will keep char 8th and above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got it... Here's what I did.. I'm giving a rough look here. Coz, I get the file names with some other function..

```
SOURCE1 = sample.war
SOURCE2 = sample1.48.war

SOURCE1_CUT = $(echo $SOURCE1 | cut -d. -f1) // removes .war part
COUNT=`echo -n $SOURCE1_CUT | wc -c` // gets the length 
SOURCE2_FINAL = `echo -n $SOURCE2 | cut -c1-$COUNT` //this cuts file simple1.48.war upto 'simple'
```

tadaaaa.... :)